# how to set and reference symbol in db slim

Tags: oracle, fitnesse, dbfit

I am using the following to set the symbol

```
mysymbol
```

to a value of 10:

```
|Divisionp     |
|=getTestValue?|
|mysymbol      |
```

java code:

```
public double GetTestValue(){
    return 10.0;

  }
```

But that does not work, i get e test fail message saying

```
[10.0] expected [mysymbol]
```

Why is this not working

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
|Divisionp    |
|getTestValue?|
|$mysymbol=   |
```

See more details at http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables